# .htaccess codeigniter redirection without changing URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have this htaccess code. What I want to accomplish is be able to redirect requests to /about and /learn to the contents of the /wordpress folder without changing the address bar

```
#Rewrite engine rules
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|import\.php|geocode\.php|robots\.txt|BingSiteAuth\.xml|y_key_88c0d00f4917d584\.html|favicon\.ico|images|img|uploads|css|js|topics|wordpress)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^about$ /wordpress [L]
RewriteRule ^learn$ /wordpress [L]
```

with the following structure with /content as the web root:

```
/content
 /wordpress
  index.php (the wordpress index.php)
 .htaccess (the one we are editing)
 index.php (the codeigniter index.php)
```

However, the htacess code does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the address bar is changing if you redirect to the wordpress root. So what I did is create a "learn" and "about" page in Wordpress so that they go /wordpress/learn and /wordpress/about.

Put this above your rules then (just below the RewriteEngine and RewriteBase declarations):

```
RewriteRule ^about/$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^learn/$ /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

requests to /about and /learn will then be redirected to /wordpress/about and /wordpress/learn respectively without changing address bars.

NOTE: This appears to have problems in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your specific rules above your wildcard rule.

Currently you have

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Before your specific rules, this rule would be triggered first.
As for your specific rules (about/learn), you might want to redirect to /wordpress/index.php

Bear in mind that if your wordpress folder has a .htaccess file that one will be used instead of your CodeIgniter/Root one, however it doesn't seem to have one via your file listing.

Comment: can I use the htaccess for Wordpress instead to redirect /learn and /about. Your answer does not work, by the way.

Comment: the redirection is still being handled by the RewriteRule that channels all request to index.php even after moving the RewriteRule(s) for /about and /learn

Comment: If there is a .htaccess in the Wordpress folder the one in your root won't even be used when using /wordpress - So there wouldn't be anything to make it work in the root .htaccess. But yes, you could  move the rewrites to your wordpress .htaccess instead - but i thought wordpress allready supported SEO urls via config?

Comment: However i did write something incorrect, the .htaccess file in the WordPress folder won't be used unless the request is /wordpress/about obviously, stupid of me.

However if you move the about/learn writes above the wildcard and change it to /wordpress/index.php it should work - however you might need to use the convetion that they use in their SEO url rewriting

Comment: sorrry, it still does not work. This is how it looks right now: http://codepad.org/pHfUe4RE

Comment: So i assume it's still getting handled by the wildcard match directive (ie being sent to CodeIgniter, not WordPress)? What does the URL request look like?

Comment: I'm confused by "what the URL looks like". AS the code is right now, /learn yields a 404 and /about redirects to the existing controller action for an about page made with Codeigniter

Comment: Just the request url, was just interested to know if you had a trailing / when requesting it, ie www.example.com/learn/ vs www.example.com/learn

Comment: following your answer and appending a trailing slash to /learn (thus /learn/), the redirection was successful but the address bar changed to /wordpress too. By the way, is there really a way for htaccess to redirect without changing the address bar much like what routers do?

Comment: It worked with a trailing slash? That's strange, my theory was that you were using trailin slashes and that's why it didn't work.

It might be changing the addressbar because your using `/wordpress`, try just `wordpress/index.php` - Just a theory, however you might wan't to look into the wordpress .htaccess and see how it handles the urls, it might be that it's redirecting to its index page because it's getting no input parameters to match.

Comment: I seemed to have made it work. Will post the answer. thanks for the comments